# Using <select> with nested objects in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-select2, angularjs-ng-change

I'd like to create an html output like this:

```
 <select>
      <option value="" class="">-- Choose category --</option>
      <optgroup label="Dogs">
           <option value="0">Great Dane</option>
           <option value="1">Lab</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="Cats">
           <option value="2">Black</option>
           <option value="3">Tabby</option>
      </optgroup>
 </select>
```

From an array like this:

```
 var animals = [{
     name: 'Dogs',
     subcats: ['great dane', 'lab']
 }, {
     name: 'Cats',
     subcats: ['tabby', 'black']
 }, ];
```

And have the model bound to the  to set 2 values, animal.type(dog or cat) and animal.subcategory.

Tried a bunch of stuff... am thinking I'll need to use ng-repeat and hack it through... any help is much appreicated.

Comment: Do you have any control of your data object, or does it *have* to look like that?

Comment: @Problematic I have control. thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you can control the model, the documentation has an example [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.directive%3aselect).

Transform your model to look like:

```
var animals = [
    {name: "great dane", subcat: "Dogs"},
    {name: "lab",        subcat: "Dogs"},
    {name: "tabby",      subcat: "Cats"},
    {name: "black",      subcat: "Cats"}
];
// and put it in the $scope
$scope.animals = animals;
```

And the select would look like:

```
<select ng-model="..." ng-options="a.name group by a.subcat for a in animals">
```

The selection will be the entire animal object with `name` and `subcat` properties.

Comment: This is a good answer. I created a plunk for it so you can see it in action. http://plnkr.co/edit/LqeGqg1HdOIkiMQrKn72?p=preview

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Do you know how to prepopulate the <select>... I tried setting $scope.animalSelection.name = 'great dane' but it didn't work.

Comment: @jessegavin I can however get it to work if I do $scope.animalSelection = animals[1]. This is not ideal...

Comment: @Andypandy I would very strongly recommend that you use a library like underscore.js which gives you easy methods for dealing with collections.  For example, you could use `_.findWhere(animals, { name: "great dane"})`  instead of `animals[1]`.   http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere

Comment: @jessegavin awesome thakns

Comment: This is really good, but I would have appreciated if it would have render infinite nesting.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative without needing to flatten your data would be to use nested `ng-repeat` directives as in [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/s7vyrvWQZgg/YCtfd_aAmEMJ).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="people in People">
<label>{{people.firstName}}</label>
<select>
<option ng-repeat-start="choice in people.Choices" ng-bind="choice.Name"></option>
<option ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="opt in choice.Options" ng-bind="' - ' + opt.Name"></option>
</select>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/2vj4PK?p=preview